# Can the servants from Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion be killed?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

The spell [(Mordenkainen's) Magnificent Mansion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magnificent-mansion) can summon up to 100 servants. These servants can't attack or cause direct harm, but they can do any action a normal human can.

I know they can't attack, but can they be attacked? Damaged? Killed?

Comment: I've removed the character-death tag; it is concerned with the death of player characters, this question is not.

Answer (score 8):

Without specifying hit points, like the spell [Unseen Servant](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/unseen-servant) does, it would be assumed the mansion's servants cannot be harmed or killed.

Answer (score 8):

### DM's Choice

The DM is free to make a choice here (since the spell does not specify).

For any DM curious how this functioned in previous editions (either for historical consistency or possible RAI insights, since the 5e writers took inspiration from previous editions), the [3.5 version of the spell](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magesMagnificentMansion.htm) said:

> The servants function as unseen servant spells except that they are
>   visible and can go anywhere in the mansion.

Answer (score 2):

It's not specified by the spell, so the DM will have to make something up.

The DM might decide that the "near-transparent" servants in the *magnificent mansion* are similar to the invisible servants created by the *unseen servant* spell.  In that case, they would have AC 10 and one hit point each.